# How do I convert this loop into a LINQ expression?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

How do I convert this loop into a LINQ expression?

```
foreach (var user in customer.Users)
{
    repositoryManager.Users.Delete(user);
}
```

Comment: What is your purpose of converting two lines of code to linq?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

[LIN**Q** is for ***Q**ueries*, not for actions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
customer.Users.ForEach(user => repositoryManager.Users.Delete(user));
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: This technically isn't linq.  But who is counting (besides SLaks)?

Comment: @Hogan you may be right, but then please name what this syntax is, for future reference.

Comment: @Cœur -- Ah, the 7 years later "for future reference".  This would be called "a function call in a loop" in the future.  (also now.)

Answer (score 0):

This one should probably also do the job in an even more concise way :

```
customer.Users.ForEach(repositoryManager.Users.Delete);
```

Now, I agree that it's a question of "Linq way of coding" (more exactly in a functional way on data sets rather than on individual objects), but not proper Linq nor query.